# The end of the life!

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

$1\ 16 \ 41 \ 55 \ 79 \ 90 \ 103 \ 120 \ 123 \ ?$

What is the last number in this different sequence! If you find it, it will be the end of the life!

Comment: If it helps anyone, the sequence of differences is: `15 25 14 24 11 13 17 3`

Comment: @Khale_Kitha get out of my dang head

Comment: @question_asker Mua ha ha ha!

Comment: A direct number to letter sequencing comes to `oynxkmqc` which appears to be meaningless, even when using an unknown 9th letter.

Comment: I found a link from 16 and 41; 16 = 4 squared, 41 = 16 + 5 squared. Unfortunately the pattern doesn't continue like this. 

Comment: Is it gonna somehow be the letter 'e'? You know, the END of the life?

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil Yeah, I assumed that part, as well, from looking at the puzzle, but didn't have a way to prove it, yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> 135

because that becomes

> APOCALYPSE.

Explantation:

> Take each letter number (i-1) mod 26 in the alphabet. The sequence must increase so, the next occurance of e is at 135.

Comment: @question_asker yes, unless this is a coincidence and the answer in completely different :-D

Comment: I was too lazy to check beyond 16

Comment: I had *just* reached the same conclusion.  I was slightly thrown by 1 -> A instead of 1 -> B as my first pass had it, but after I adjusted it, I saw you'd posted.

Comment: If noticed that the two first spelled 'AP', so from there on it was simple.

Comment: I'm too distracted by the plantation.  However, good job, Carl =D

Comment: Made a slight counting error, should be 135 instead of 134...

Comment: @Khale_Kitha you mean the former plantation?

Comment: @Kevin Yup!  That's the one.

Comment: Just a fun bit of code `[1,16,41,55,79,90,103,120,123,135].map(n=>(~-n%26+10).toString(36))`